# change which toggle is selected on page load

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out a solution where i can select which toggle is displayed on page load.   At the minute, when the page loads, it is set to Pay Annually.  How would i change my code so that it is set to Pay Monthly on page load?.  I want the ability to quickly swap them for a/b tests.

I've attached my CodePen also - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jonimmsCC/pen/mdmxrVa)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkBoxes = $("input[name='toggle']");
  toggle();
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    toggle();
  });

  function toggle() {
    if (checkBoxes.prop("checked")) {
      $('#coreMonthlyText,#coreMonthlyPrice').show();
      $('#coreAnnuallyText,#coreAnnuallyPrice').hide();

    } else {
      $('#coreMonthlyText,#coreMonthlyPrice').hide();
      $('#coreAnnuallyText,#coreAnnuallyPrice').show();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.pricing-box {
  background: red;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 30%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.toggle-switch {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.toggle-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-switch,
.toggle-switch span {
  border-radius: 35px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.toggle-switch span {
  border-width: 2px;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}

.toggle-switch input:checked+span+span,
.toggle-switch input+span {
  border-color: #444;
  background-color: white;
}

.toggle-switch input+span+span,
.toggle-switch input:checked+span {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#coreMonthlyText,
#coreMonthlyPrice,
#coreAnnuallyText,
#coreAnnuallyPrice {
  display: none;
}

#proMonthlyText,
#proMonthlyPrice,
#proAnnuallyText,
#proAnnuallyPrice {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pricing-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="core">
        <h2>Core</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div id="coreAnnuallyPrice" class="coreAnnuallyPrice">
        $2,399/yr<br /> Normally $3,588/yr
      </div>
      <div id="coreMonthlyPrice" class="coreMonthlyPrice">
        $299/pm<br /> first 2 months free
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <label for="toggle" class="toggle-switch">
        <input class="toggle-button" id="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle" data-checked="coreAnnuallyPrice,coreAnnuallyText" data-not-checked="coreMonthlyPrice,coreMonthlyText">
        <span>pay annually</span>
        <span>pay monthly</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: a fast solution could be to add `.trigger("click")` to the end of your click event. like `$("#toggle").click(function() { toggle(); }).trigger("click");` and then remove the `toggle();` that is above your click event

Comment: You can also improve your jquery code a bit like https://jsfiddle.net/4gcqmf73/